# Minimal and characteristic polynomials 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Is there an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ such that the minimal polynomial $\mu_A$ and characteristic polynomial $c_A$ have different degrees?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, consider the identity matrix $I_n$ with $n>1$, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial of any $n\times n$ matrix has degree $n$, while the minimal polynomial has degree at most $n$.

To construct an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that has degree $\operatorname{deg}(\mu_A)=d$ for some $d\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, consider the following matrix whose eigenvlaues are all equal to $\lambda$:
$$
A = \operatorname{diag}(J_{d}(\lambda),J_{1}(\lambda),\dots,J_1(\lambda))
$$
which has one Jordan block of size $d$ and $n-d$ Jordan blocks of size $1$, and we use the notation
$$
J_r(\lambda) = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & & \cdots & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$
to denote the $r\times r$ Jordan block.

The characteristic polynomial of this $A$ is $c_A(t )=(t-\lambda)^n$ while its minimal polynomial is $\mu_A(t) = (t-\lambda)^d$.

For example, the matrix 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix} = \operatorname{diag}(J_{3}(\lambda),J_1(\lambda))
$$
has characteristic polynomial $(t-\lambda)^4$ with degree 4, but minimal polynomial $(t-\lambda)^3$ with degree 3.

Comment: You somehow got your $d$'s and $n$'s mixed up. If you want an $n\times n$ matrix, then you should not start with a Jordan block $J_n$. I suppose you meant $J_d$ there; also interchange $d\leftrightarrow n$ in the remainder of that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In general if one forms a block diagonal matrix $D=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with $A$ and $B$ square matrices, the characteristic polynomials satisfy $\chi_D=\chi_A\chi_B$ (I think the notation $\chi_A$ is more common here than $c_A$), while the minimal polynomials satisfy $\mu_D=\operatorname{lcm}(\mu_A,\mu_B)$ (their least common multiple). This gives you ample opportunity to make the two different, to begin with by for instance taking $A=B$.